# Ubuntu.com log in with Ubuntu One not accepting valid credentials

Tags: login, password

I tried to log in to Ubuntu one using my long held gmail credentials but they were not accepted.  I used the copy from previous logon and carefully checked the password which was correct but still it is not accepted.  I selected password reset but no email is sent to my gmail account.

What has happened and how do I reset.  Why are perfectly good credentials rejected?

Comment: Sounds just like what happened to me the other day, other logins worked but trying a direct login to ubuntu.com to get ubutnu pro failed.  Try clearing any old cookies for the problem site -- my problem just went away, so not sure what fixed it -- never did 2FA.